# Partial sums of $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n + 1)(n + 2)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, partial-fractions

I have to calculate $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n + 1)(n + 2)}$. I decompose into partial sums and I get
$$S_{m}=\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{-1}{x+1}+\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{1}{2(x+2)}+\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{1}{2x}$$
But I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: You want $n$ where you’ve written $x.$ The problem with your sums is that none of them converge.

Comment: This is a "telescoping" sum. Write down ALL the terms in your expansion, and you will see that nearly all of them cancel out.

Comment: And see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1566058/show-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n1n2n3-is-convergent-using-partial?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convergence of semi-telescopic series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+2)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233748/convergence-of-semi-telescopic-series-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1kk1k)

Answer (score 4):

Hint: See that $$ \frac{2}{n(n + 1)(n + 2)} = \frac{(n+2) - n}{n(n + 1)(n + 2)} = \frac{1}{n(n+1)} - \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}$$ and now the sum is telescopic!

Comment: @peter a g Yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach can work.

One way  to start from your answer is to ask what is the total coefficient of $\frac1k$ in your sums, for $k=1,\dots,m+2.$

Turns out, for $k=3,\dots,m$ the sum is $\frac{1}{2}-1+\frac12=0.$

Then you need to deal with the additional cases $k=1,2,m+1,m+2.$

---

Alternatively, note that your partial fractions can be written:

$$\begin{align}a_n&=\left(\frac{1}{2n}-\frac1{2(n+1)}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2(n+1)}-\frac1{2(n+2)}\right)\\&=b_n-b_{n+1}\end{align}$$
where $$b_n=\frac{1}{2n}-\frac1{2(n+1)}$$